# xcode instrument shows memory leaks on returning char pointer

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, char, xcode-instruments

I have a function which returns collection of strings. All the memory allocation is done inside that function, as the size of the string varies each time that function is called. All allocation is freed after the use of those strings. But when I run my application on a simulator with an instrument for leak testing, it shows me the location where I actually `malloc`ed the `char*`s.

My confusion is, though I am freeing all the strings properly, is it still considered as a leak for my application? Or this is kind of wrong observation by xcode instrument?

Comment: How do you know that you are freeing *all* these strings properly, especially since the instrumentation tells you otherwise?

Comment: First, show the code. Second, when Instruments identifies a leak, it shows you where the leaked memory was allocated. That's not necessarily where it was leaked. Any code which has influence on the lifetime of that memory allocation could be responsible for the leak. Any over-retain or under-release would be responsible. You have to review the retain/release history of an individual leaked object to see which code is to blame.

Comment: I am using both CPP and Objective C together. In my native cpp function I am allocating memory and return these strings. In Objective C section First I use those strings and then frees all strings. The location instruments shows me as leak is at the malloc'ing over char pointer and I am handling it properly after use. Is there any way to observe currently allocated total memory for my application instance?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the tool you are using might be right, or it might have given you a false positive. There's no way of telling with the information available in your post...

Generally, I tend to assume that warnings given by debugging tools are valid, until I can proove otherwise. Thus, in your case, I would be looking at the code to find out why the debugging tool has flagged it, rather than just dismissing it as an unexplained false positive; even more so when I'm dealing with stuff I have little experience with.